# Android upload to store error - file is invalid: ERROR getting 'android:name' attribute:

Tags: android, upload, store

I am uploading my draft application .apk file myapp.apk to market.android.com  When I click upload I get the error message:

```
The file is invalid: ERROR getting 'android:name' attribute:
```

This app works fine in the simulator and the AndroidManifest.xml looks correct.  The app has also been signed correctly.  Any thoughts ideas or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml?  My best guess without truly knowing is that one or more parts of your app are missing that attribute.  Also, tonight they've been making changes to the market uploader, and I think some of us probably hit in the middle of a bug or two that they've now fixed.  I hit one point where my app was rejected because my icon was wrong or something.  I closed my browser and retried and it worked.

Comment: Hi Tony, I changed browsers just to make sure.  Just added the XML but it is not showing correctly.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml document is in Google docs here https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1vSsSHktIMaXq_P-cYY04QICFMKZRAGXfLjOO8klXk9A

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the AndroidManifest.xml before activity the permissions need to be set.

Answer (score 0):

In the android file you might have given in `.....uses permission=""</uses permission>`
 you might have did a typo mistake or it might be a null..
If you cant post it.. just paste the code.., so that I can spot the error